# groupby that contain more than one element

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to recover in a DataFrame the rows of the groups (by TYPE) that contain more than one element.

```
TYPE VALEUR
M1   A
M1   B
M2   A
```

the result should be :

```
TYPE VALEUR
M1   A
M1   B
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Have no idea for an elegant solution. Here's my stupid one:

```
In [149]: m = df.groupby('TYPE').size() > 1

In [151]: df[df['TYPE'].map(m)]
Out[151]: 
  TYPE VALEUR
0   M1      A
1   M1      B
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use `ix` if you set `TYPE` as the index first:

```
df.set_index("TYPE", inplace=True)
df.ix[df.groupby(level=0).size() > 1]
```