# How to filter all rows that belong to groups with more than 1 member?

Tags: python, pandas, select, dataframe, group-by

I have a similar question as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15786686/groupby-that-contain-more-than-one-element).

I have a dataframe like this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': list(range(7)),
                   'B': ['a', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'c', 'b', 'b'],
                   'C': ['x', 'x', 'x', 'z', 'z', 'y', 'x']}
                  )

   A  B  C
0  0  a  x
1  1  b  x
2  2  a  x
3  3  c  z
4  4  c  z
5  5  b  y
6  6  b  x
```

I want to `groupby` columns `B` and `C` and then select all rows from `df` that have a group size greater than 1.

My **desired outcome** would be

```
   A  B  C
0  0  a  x
1  1  b  x
2  2  a  x
3  3  c  z
4  4  c  z
6  6  b  x
```

So I can do

```
gs_bool = df.groupby(['B', 'C']).size() > 1
```

which gives

```
B  C
a  x     True
b  x     True
   y    False
c  z     True
dtype: bool
```

How do I now feed this back to `df`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are really close - need [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html):

```
gs_bool = df.groupby(['B', 'C'])['B'].transform('size') > 1
print (gs_bool)
0     True
1     True
2     True
3     True
4     True
5    False
6     True
Name: B, dtype: bool
```

---

```
df = df[gs_bool]
print (df)
   A  B  C
0  0  a  x
1  1  b  x
2  2  a  x
3  3  c  z
4  4  c  z
6  6  b  x
```

Answer (score 2):

IIUC:

```
In [38]: df.groupby(['B','C']).filter(lambda x: len(x) > 1)
Out[38]:
   A  B  C
0  0  a  x
1  1  b  x
2  2  a  x
3  3  c  z
4  4  c  z
6  6  b  x
```

Comment: @jezrael, is it __much__ slower?

Comment: @jezrael, yeah, it's approx. 1.8 times slower for 700.000 rows DF

Comment: I find it - [timings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47118796/2901002). But it depends of sizes of groups - first vary gad times for many groups, second better times for less. ;)