# Deleting rows in pandas that occur less than a certain amount based on three columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe with three columns, and I want to drop all rows where the unique combination
of df['person'], df['id'], and df['day'] only occur twice or less. Is there a simple way to do this in pandas?

```
[In]:
person  id  day
1       2   1
1       2   1
1       2   1
1       2   1
1       1   1
1       1   1
1       1   1
1       0   1
1       2   2
2       2   2
2       2   2
2       2   2
1       3   1
1       3   1
1       3   1
1       0   1
2       2   2

[Out]:
person  id  day
1       2   1
1       2   1
1       2   1
1       1   1
1       1   1
1       1   1
2       2   2
2       2   2
2       2   2
1       3   1
1       3   1
1       3   1
2       2   2
```

Comment: Quite similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47308335/how-to-filter-all-rows-that-belong-to-groups-with-more-than-1-member)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can using `transform` build a new para info

```
df['Info']=df.groupby(list(df)).id.transform('count')
df
Out[444]: 
    person  id  day  Info
0        1   2    1     4
1        1   2    1     4
2        1   2    1     4
3        1   2    1     4
4        1   1    1     3
5        1   1    1     3
6        1   1    1     3
7        1   0    1     2
8        1   2    2     1
9        2   2    2     4
10       2   2    2     4
11       2   2    2     4
12       1   3    1     3
13       1   3    1     3
14       1   3    1     3
15       1   0    1     2
16       2   2    2     4
```

Then you can do

```
df[df.Info>2].drop('Info',1)
Out[447]: 
    person  id  day
0        1   2    1
1        1   2    1
2        1   2    1
3        1   2    1
4        1   1    1
5        1   1    1
6        1   1    1
9        2   2    2
10       2   2    2
11       2   2    2
12       1   3    1
13       1   3    1
14       1   3    1
16       2   2    2
```

Comment: `df[df.groupby([df.person,df.id,df.day])['day'].transform('count').gt(2)]`  boolean filtering :-)

Comment: While both answers gave the same results that I expected, this one was over 25 times faster than the other one: 0.37s versus 9.56. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
df.groupby(['person','id','day']).filter(lambda x:x.shape[0]>2)
```

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.filter.html